# set specific date in Date Picker IOS

Tags: ios, date

I have a Date Picker on my story board but I don't want it to default to today's date. I want the date to start at July 15 1998. In the attribute inspector i set the date to that and it shows it on my story board but when I launch the application it is still on today's date. Is there something else I have to do for it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[yourDatePicker setDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:900478800]];
```

or if you want to be fancy:

```
[yourDatePicker setDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:900478800] animated:YES];
```

you can put this in your viewDidLoad:

Comment: do i have to create an NSDate object first? When i type that code I get an error saying unexpected interface name 'NSDate'

Comment: well, the 'dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970' is a class method & so it returns an NSDate object without you having to initialize anything.

Comment: ok thanks that worked, can I just ask you one more thing? I also need the date from July, 1st 1867, how would I do that?

Comment: just get the number of seconds since the unix epoch (1/1/1970). here's a link that calculates it for you: http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm : just set the epoch to 0 & hit 'To Epoch' with your date & fill it in for the 'dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970' method

Comment: of course there are other ways to do it: 'dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:', 'dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow' & 'dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:'